# ScrollTop and ScrollTo Not working when changing innerHtml in a Div

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, scrolltop, scrollto

I've read a bunch of topics on this and can't get any of the solutions I've seen to work. I have a Div "Section" where the contents (images, ext,etc) change by changing the innerhtml of a p.  I can't figure out why I can't get it to scroll back to the top of #section when I switch between the 'panes' I've created by switching the innerhtml.  In other words you load a pane by clicking on an image/text, you scroll down and see contents, then when you click into another 'pane' I just want it to scroll to the top.  Any ideas?

This is what I currently have-

```
     case 1:

                    text = '[new html] ';

                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
                    document.getElementById("section").scrollTo(0,0);
                    break;
```

This is the HTML in my original body when it loads-

```
<div id="section"><div id="sectionwrap">

<p id="demo"></p>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Please formulate a jsfiddle or codesnippet with your code :)

Comment: I'll try to recreate the scenario in JSfiddle real quick but my actual code is a whole bunch of stuff

Comment: I've never used Jsfiddle, can't get it to work so far. Just figuring it out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Breh/huajt06w/   Don't know why the function wont run in this fiddle

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you never call the function z

Comment: It's supposed to fire when you click the aa div

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted? It's a little difficult to understand your question so bear with me :)

```js
window.onload = function(){
var x;
document.getElementById('aa').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("section").scrollTop = 0;
  document.getElementById("section").style.background = 'red';
};
};
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Impact;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#sectionwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1600px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 122, .5);
}
#sidebar {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 1000px;
}
#aa {
  background: blue;
}
#aa:hover {
  background: green;
}
#section {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="section">
    <div id="sectionwrap">
      <p id="demo">1
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="aa" onclick="z(9)">2</div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: See this won't run the script from document.getElementById('ab').onclick after you run the first function in the identical way.  all of this is off topic from my original question, but may be related:  http://jsfiddle.net/Breh/72c2htho/

Comment: Sorry I've never used jsfiddle like I said, but I'm not getting why my functions don't call in this one:   http://jsfiddle.net/Breh/mLkfrvby/  if I'm using an onclick ref in my div reference.  I use this 100 times in my current JS page and the functions call.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone Else has this issue I got it to work.

I have a switch that changed between sets of innerHTML for the #section div (and toggles some other cosmetic things).  If you have a similar setup within a page, Call your ScrollTop command before your switch.  This achieved what I wanted which was to change the innerHTML by using a switch with different setups in each switch case, but have the div containing the new html to scroll back to the top when the "changing the contents" function was called.